# Setting up iBeacons from webapp

Tags: javascript, php, html, ibeacon

For a school project my friend and I are trying to set up iBeacons by using a webapp. We want to use a simple form on our webapp that tells the beacon what data to send to the people who are in proximity of the beacon.

For example; I add an event to the beacon by using the webapp and as I add it it gets add to the beacon. The beacon sends out notifications to the users until I add a new event to the beacon.

Would this be possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacons do not send data other than a three part identifier (a 16 byte proximity UUID that uniquely identifiers your organization or company, a 2 byte major and a two byte minor.) It does not really make sense for the web app to alter the beacon transmission itself because it sends so little data.  It also doesn't make much sense because beacons are generally designed to be read only.

Another way to accomplish what you want with a web app is to build a lookup web service that returns the information to display for the beacon's three part beacon identifier.

An app on iOS would call this web service to get a display message for a beacon with a given uuid/major/minor after it detects it.  It could use the results to display a notification.

A web page in your web app would allow changing the display message for a given set of beacon identntifiers.

This would accomplish what you want in a different way.

Comment: Would it be possible to work with a drop down form for selecting the UUID of a certain beacon and changing the display message with a simple form? I have no experience at all with iBeacons, but we're trying to prove the usefulness of the beacons in an educational setting. The idea we had was sending push messages to students smartphones with important information they'll usually miss, like administration tasks they still need to complete. i've been doing research and noticed that you can't send push messages with a webapp (yet). I'm looking for a solution for this problem.

Comment: Yes, you can set up a drop down Luke you suggest.  You normally build a beacon app to send a *local notification* when the iBeacon is detected.

Comment: Would there be any online resources where I can see examples of a webpage where this is done? I tried googling it but I can't find any...

Comment: What web app programming language do you know?

Comment: HTML, CSS, php, JS, jQuery

Comment: Try this tutorial. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-your-own-web-service-for-an-ios-app-part-one/